# My second segment IP can not access its gateway

Tags: networking, interface

I have a VLAN which have `43.24.227.38/29` and `192.168.33.238/29` in it, I configured IP on one interface, you see bellow:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 43.24.227.35
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        gateway 43.24.227.38

auto eno1:0
iface eno1:0 inet static
        address 43.24.227.36
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
auto eno1:1
iface eno1:1 inet static
        address 192.168.33.235
        netmask 255.255.255.248
```

but now I can not ping `192.168.33.238` from my server, is there I need add any static route?

Comment: Why do you have two subnets on one VLAN? Has your ISP actually given you 43.24.227.35/29? Is 192.168.33.238 on the same L2 segment as 43.24.227.35?

Comment: Yes, there are two segments.

Comment: When you say you cannot ping what do you mean? Network unreachable or ping timeout?